# perform aggregated subquery plan

Tags: sql-server-2012

Looking for an elegant way to avoid the error message
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
SELECT AccountName
 , SUM(CASE
       WHEN CallFlag = 1 AND Attempts < c.nMaxAttempts
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END)CallRecords
 , SUM(CASE
       WHEN CRC IN(
                   SELECT szCRC COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                     FROM ContactCenter..CallDispositionMap
                     WHERE bBadRecord = 1)
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END)BadRecords
FROM Calls;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the sub select. And also you need to use the `Group BY` On the query. Try this,

```
SELECT
  AccountName,
  SUM(CallRecords) AS CallRecords,
  SUM(BadRecords) AS BadRecords
FROM
  (
   SELECT AccountName
 , (CASE
       WHEN CallFlag = 1 AND Attempts < c.nMaxAttempts
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END)CallRecords
 , (CASE
       WHEN CRC IN(
                   SELECT szCRC COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                     FROM ContactCenter..CallDispositionMap
                     WHERE bBadRecord = 1)
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END)BadRecords
  FROM Calls) AS data
  GROUP BY AccountName
```